# Disable/Enable ApplicationInsights Telemetry dynamically

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-application-insights

I implemented Application Insigths in the frontend applciation and I want to disable/enable it based on a variable that can change over the lifetime of the applications. (e.g. user declined Application Insights consent => Disable Telemetry)

What I tried is:

```
appInsights.appInsights.config.disableTelemetry = true
```

however if I try to enable it back setting `disableTelemetry =false` this is not working anymore.

Is anything else that I need to make to persist this change or is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [telemetry filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#javascript-web-applications) for that:

```js
var filteringFunction = (envelope) => {
  if (condition) {
      return false; // Do not send telemetry
  }

  return true; // Do send the telemetry
};
```

Register the filter like this:

```js
appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer(filteringFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

- While Peter's answer is correct, I have different approach where instead of using telemetry filters we can stop the application insights object itself from starting to log to app insights.
- Here in the following code based on the value of the variable `a` it will start the app insight service.
- So, we will run `appInsights.start();` only for a particular for value of variable `a`.

```
import { createRequire } from  "module";
const  require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

let  appInsights = require('applicationinsights');

appInsights.setup("<Your connection String>")
    .setAutoCollectConsole(true, true);

var  a = 10 ;
if(a==10)
{appInsights.start();}

console.log("Hello World ");
```

Here I am running the code twice but with different value of variable `a`.

[image]

Here in application insights one log appear.

[image]

Comment: Ok but this happens only once at the initialization. What if during the application, the user declines the Application Insights consent and now I immediatly need to disable telemetry?

Comment: Well in that case you will have to use the `TelemetryInitializer` from peter's answer as it will depending upon your condition  you can then choose whether to add the telemetry or not